# backbone.js unix dates in underscore.js

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, momentjs

I'm trying to get it right with my unix dates in an underscore js template.

In my template I have two unix dates coming from a backbone view that initialises this current template and passing the two dates as arguments.

In my template I now need to compare the two dates and get how many days it is between them. I cant do that in my view. I need to do it in the underscore template.

I'm using moment.js.

```
<% collection.each(function(model,index) { %>
            <%
                uploaded = moment(new Date(model.get("uploaded_date"))) 
                servertime = moment(now) /*now is passed in as a variable since its not in the collection*/
            %>

            <p>
                <%= uploaded.diff(servertime, 'days') %>
            </p>
<% }); %>
```

I'm trying to use the diff() but all I get back is "0"
When I print the actual date variables I get the correct unix dates.

Anyone knows hows to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code and it's working :

```
var uploaded = moment(new Date(1391185930000));
var servertime = moment(new Date(1390321930000)); // now at the date I wrote that example :)
alert(uploaded.diff(servertime, 'days'));
```

First try to add a ';' at the end of the two first lines of code.

What your 'now' variable looks like ? Have you tried this 'var servertime = moment();'

Comment: You shouldn't need to initialize servertime moment with `new Date()`, initializing a new moment with no parameters has the same effect e.g. `var servertime = moment();`

Comment: Thank you. The thing is tho, that im working with unix date. so a date looks like this for example: 1389610067. and my now-variable is the time of the server, coming from server-side by a json-call.